# bordermatrix with blocks

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays, bordermatrix

I need to write a complicated matrix, that has a structure as in the attached picture. 
[image: matrix example]

Answer (score 23):

The [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) package allows to do complex border matrix with relatively simple code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{blockarray}{cc|cccc|cccc}
    & 1\dots 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
    \begin{block}{c(c|cccc|cccc@{\hspace*{5pt}})}
    A'_1 & A_1 & \BAmulticolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{$I$}}&\BAmulticolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{$I$}}\\
    A'_2 & A_2 & &&&&&&&\\
    A'_3 & A_3 & &&&&&&&\\
    A'_4 & A_4 & &&&&&&&\\
    \cline{1-10}% don't use \hline
    B'_1 & B_1 & \BAmulticolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{$J$}}&\BAmulticolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{$I$}}\\
    B'_2 & B_2 & &&&&&&&\\
    B'_3 & B_3 & &&&&&&&\\
    B'_4 & B_4 & &&&&&&&\\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. I didn't know this package before. It seems `blkarray` provides better spacing.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\def\Big#1{\makebox(0,0){\huge#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cc|c|c}
 & 1\ldots18&19\,20\,21\,22&23\,24\,25\,26\\ 
 \begin{block}{c(c|c|c)}
   A_1^\prime & A_1 &        &        \\  
   A_2^\prime & A_2 & \Big{I}& \Big{I}\\  
   A_3^\prime & A_3 &        &        \\
   A_4^\prime & A_4 &        &        \\\cline{1-4}
   B_1^\prime & B_1 &        &        \\  
   B_2^\prime & B_2 &\Big{J} & \Big{I}\\  
   B_3^\prime & B_3 &        &        \\  
   B_4^\prime & B_4 &        &        \\  
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you write `^\prime` and not simply `'`? The latter expands to the former and is much clearer.

Comment: @Hendrik: you are right in this case it makes no sense. I did it by default. HOwever, cannot remember where I had to use instead of the accent

Comment: This should be added to your `mathmode.pdf`.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to everyone. I managed to find solution myself as well. I have used package `kbordermatrix`. However very often math journals want to typeset the tex file themselves and they don't have all the packages. I'm sure that at least one variant will work. So thank again:) My solution is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\kbordermatrix{
& 1 \ldots 18 & \vrule & 19 \text{ } 20 \text{ } 21 \text{ } 22 & \vrule & 23 \text{ }  24 \text{ } 25 \text{ } 26 \\           
  \begin{array}{c} \chi(A'_1) \\ \chi(A'_2) \\ \chi(A'_3) \\ \chi(A'_4) \end{array}
& \begin{array}{c} \chi(A_1)  \\ \chi(A_2)  \\ \chi(A_3)  \\ \chi(A_4)  \end{array}
& \vrule & I & \vrule& I \\ \hline
  \begin{array}{c} \chi(B'_1) \\ \chi(B'_2) \\ \chi(B'_3) \\ \chi(B'_4) \end{array}
& \begin{array}{c} \chi(B_1)  \\ \chi(B_2)  \\ \chi(B_3)  \\ \chi(B_4)  \end{array}
& \vrule & J & \vrule& I  } , 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You should have enough rep now, so I edited in the picture.

Comment: I've tried to improve the formatting of your code a bit. Hope that's OK.

Comment: Of course if you absolutely need a package as well as a self-contained .tex file, you can always just copy and paste the .sty file content in your main .tex file. Minus the `\ProvidesPackage` stuff of course.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `multirow` and `bigdelim` package for this matrix. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc|cc|ccc}
  && x & a & b & c & d \\
A &\ldelim({4}{0.5em}& x
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}*{ab}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}*{cd}}
  & \rdelim){4}{0.5em} \\
B && y &&&& \\
\hline
C && x 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}*{ab}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}*{cd}} \\
D && y &&&& \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Plain-kru represenz:

```
\font\Large=cmr10 at 20pt
\newcount\rowcount\rowcount=3
\def\fudge#1{\smash{\hbox{\Large#1}}}
\def\doublyso{\kern-.5em\smash{\vrule height \rowcount em depth .2em}\hidewidth}
$\bordermatrix{
  \global\everycr{\noalign{\global\advance\rowcount by 1}}
  &1\ldots18&19\;20\;21\;22&23\;24\;25\;26 \cr
  A_1'&A_1\cr
  A_2'&A_2\cr
  A_3'&A_3&\fudge I&\fudge I\cr
  A_4'&A_4\cr
  \noalign{\smallskip\hrule\smallskip}
  B_1'&B_1\cr
  B_2'&B_2\cr
  B_3'&B_3&\fudge J&\fudge I\cr
  B_4'&B_4&\doublyso&\doublyso\cr
}$
\everycr={}
\bye
```

[image: output]

In my "*imitation of `\atopwithdelims`-line of thought*"-spree, I made one for `\bordermatrix` as well (which is the Plain `\bordermatrix` with only the delims made as arguments):

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\bordermatrixwithdelims#1#2#3{\begingroup \m@th
  \setbox0=\vbox{\def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\kern2pt\global\let\cr=\endline}}
    \ialign{$##$\hfil\kern2pt\kern\p@renwd&\thinspace\hfil$##$\hfil
      &&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \omit\strut\hfil\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
      #3\crcr\omit\strut\cr}}
  \setbox2=\vbox{\unvcopy0 \global\setbox1=\lastbox}
  \setbox2=\hbox{\unhbox1 \unskip \global\setbox1=\lastbox}
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\kern\wd1\kern-\p@renwd \left#1 \kern-\wd1
    \global\setbox1=\vbox{\box1\kern2pt}
    \vcenter{\kern-\ht1 \unvbox0 \kern-\baselineskip} \,\right#2$}
  \null\;\vbox{\kern\ht1\box2}\endgroup}
\catcode`@=12
%
\def\cbordermatrix#1{\bordermatrixwithdelims[]{#1}}
\def\bbordermatrix#1{\bordermatrixwithdelims\{\}{#1}}
\def\vbordermatrix#1{\bordermatrixwithdelims||{#1}}
%
$$
\bordermatrix{&[a]&[b]\cr &1&2\cr&3&4}
\cbordermatrix{&[a]&[b]\cr &1&2\cr&3&4}
\bbordermatrix{&[a]&[b]\cr &1&2\cr&3&4}
\vbordermatrix{&[a]&[b]\cr &1&2\cr&3&4}
$$
\bye
```

[image: bmatrices]

So to achieve the look of which the OP settled on, one could just substitute the call to `\bordermatrix` in my original answer with `\cbordermatrix`

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{cc|cccc|cccc}
     & 1...18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
A_1' & A_1    & \Block{4-4}<\Large\bfseries>{\text{I}} &&&& \Block{4-4}<\Large\bfseries>{\text{I}} \\
A_2' & A_2    & \\
A_3' & A_3    & \\
A_4' & A_4    & \\
\hline
B_1' & B_1    & \Block{4-4}<\Large\bfseries>{\text{J}} &&&& \Block{4-4}<\Large\bfseries>{\text{I}} \\
B_2' & B_2    & \\
B_3' & B_3    & \\
B_4' & B_4    & \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({2-2}{9-10})
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

If you want the rules only in the main matrix, it's also possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceMatrix}
     & 1...18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
A_1' & A_1    & \Block{4-4}<\Large\bfseries>{\text{I}} &&&& \Block{4-4}<\Large\bfseries>{\text{I}} \\
A_2' & A_2    & \\
A_3' & A_3    & \\
A_4' & A_4    & \\
B_1' & B_1    & \Block{4-4}<\Large\bfseries>{\text{J}} &&&& \Block{4-4}<\Large\bfseries>{\text{I}} \\
B_2' & B_2    & \\
B_3' & B_3    & \\
B_4' & B_4    & \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({2-2}{9-10})[vlines={1,5},hlines=4]
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]