# Math, cells above a bmatrix

Tags: math-mode

How would one typset an array with cells above a `bmatrix`, something like

```
[a] & [b]
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
```

Where somehow the `[a]` and `[b]` cells would appear aligned and above the `bmatrix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a modified `\bordermatrix`. It is described in [`mathmode`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/voss-mathmode.html).

You can also use [`blkarray` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/blkarray.html) for convenience, see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/bordermatrix-with-blocks/10155#10155).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cc}
[a] & [b] \\
\begin{block}{[cc]}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a solution within the math environment?  Great solution, but I need it to be within an equation environment.

Comment: @ccook: `\[ ... \]` is the math environment. You can replace it with `euqation` env.

Comment: I should have made less of an assumption.  I'm trying to typeset it for wikimedia and it doesn't recognize the blocks :(

Comment: @ccook: Wiki uses part of TeX syntax for math formulas. However, wiki does **NOT** have full TeX abilities. You'll have to use the restricted TeX described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Editing_Math

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\[...\]` you can use `$...$`. one example with arrays and one with `\multicolumn`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{cc}
[a] & [b]\\
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
3 
\end{array}\right. &
\left.\begin{array}{c}
2\\
4 
\end{array}\right] 
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{cc}
[a] & [b]\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{%
\begin{bmatrix}
~1 & 2~ \\
~3 & 4~
\end{bmatrix}}%
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This also does not work for wikipedia. Even `\multicolumn` is not supported by mediawiki.

Comment: then we do it withpout `\multicolumn` ...

Answer (score 1):

For wikipedia only, you can use this manual dirty version. It is tested in Wikipedia's sandbox.

```
<math>
\begin{matrix}
\begin{matrix} [a] & [b] \end{matrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
</math>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well for wikimedia.  I did have to push the header around with \quad, but as you said, quick and dirty for wikimedia.

Answer (score 0):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and its key `first-row`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row]
[a] & [b] \\
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]