# Matrix with labels

Tags: labels, matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bordermatrix with blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/bordermatrix-with-blocks)

I'm attempting to copy the matrix on this page: http://tiny.cc/ipliw with the labels outside the matrix. I can make the matrix (given below) but I don't know how to include the labels.

```
\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc|ccccc}
+0&+1&\cdots &+j&\cdots & +k & \cdots &+0'&+1'&\cdots & +j' & \cdots \\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\cdots &\cdots &\cdots & \varepsilon_{i j} k &\cdots & \varepsilon_{i k} A_{i k} &
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \varepsilon'_{i j} k' & \cdots \\ 
&&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
\alpha_0 0' & \alpha_1 1'& \cdots & \alpha_j j'& \cdots & \alpha_k k' & \cdots & 
-\alpha_0 0 & -\alpha_1 1 & \cdots & -\alpha_j j & \cdots
\end{array}\right)
```

I've tried using things like \bordermatrix but I struggle to include the blocks.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this previous question help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/bordermatrix-with-blocks

Comment: See the answer to this question: [bordermatrix with blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10122/).  Your question is pretty much an exact duplicate of it.

Comment: @Alan Munn: There seems to be one difference: the horizontal rule does not go beyond the left paren.

Comment: @morbusg Sure, but that's just a matter of changing the `\cline{1-10}` to `\cline{2-10}`.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Oh, right! Definitely a duplicate, then.