# How to use Line in Matrix

Tags: matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\bordermatrix with brackets [ ] instead of parentheses ( )](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55054/bordermatrix-with-brackets-instead-of-parentheses)

I need to write a complicated matrix, that has a structure as in the attached picture

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: search for `bordermatrix`

Comment: See: [\bordermatrix with brackets instead of parentheses](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55054) and [bordermatrix with blocks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/bordermatrix-with-blocks). I suggest closing this question as duplicate or too localized, since it's just a "do this for me" without much use for the public.