# I want to write a matrix like the one in the picture

Tags: matrices

I need to write a matrix like this.

[image]

I don't know how to add those letters outer of matrix. I tried 
```

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
%% letters
%% matrix body
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

to format multiple line formula but failed. I have no idea how to do this. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30791/array-with-labeling-columns?lq=1 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/bordermatrix-with-blocks helps.

Comment: Good to hear. We'll close this as a duplicate then.