# How can I have a multicolumn label with blockarray before the block portion?

Tags: matrices, multirow, multicolumn, blkarray

I'm trying to have a multicolumn label but that doesn't seem to work.
When I run the following, it fails:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{C} =
    \begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\text{Predicted}} & \\
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n & \\
        \begin{block}{c(ccccc)c}
            1 & c_{11}   & c_{12} & c_{13} & \dots & c_{1n} & \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{\text{Actual}}} \\
            2 & c_{21}   & c_{22} & c_{23} & \dots & c_{2n} & \\
            \vdots & \vdots   & \ddots &        &       & \vdots & \\
            n & c_{n1}   & c_{n2} & c_{n3} & \dots & c_{nn} & \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}
```

This is the closest I've gotten to a non-failing version but am unable to get the multicolumn label to work.

```
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{C} =
    \begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
        & \text{Predicted} & & & & \\
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n & \\
        \begin{block}{c(ccccc)c}
            1 & c_{11}   & c_{12} & c_{13} & \dots & c_{1n} & \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{\text{Actual}}} \\
            2 & c_{21}   & c_{22} & c_{23} & \dots & c_{2n} & \\
            \vdots & \vdots   & \ddots &        &       & \vdots & \\
            n & c_{n1}   & c_{n2} & c_{n3} & \dots & c_{nn} & \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: Single Column Labels Output]

How can I get the "Predicted" label to span the remaining columns?

I'm happy to switch to another environment from blockarray but it seemed like this was the recommended package after looking at multiple alternatives for labeled matrixes.

Full document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    % PACKAGES
    \usepackage{blkarray}
    \usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{C} =
        \begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
            & \text{Predicted} & & & & & \\
            & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n & \\
            \begin{block}{c(ccccc)c}
                1 & c_{11}   & c_{12} & c_{13} & \dots & c_{1n} & \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{\text{Actual}}} \\
                2 & c_{21}   & c_{22} & c_{23} & \dots & c_{2n} & \\
                \vdots & \vdots   & \ddots &        &       & \vdots & \\
                n & c_{n1}   & c_{n2} & c_{n3} & \dots & c_{nn} & \\
            \end{block}
        \end{blockarray}
    \end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please always post a complete small document, not disconnected fragments, so people can run and debug the code. I'm surprised `multirow` works with `blockarray` at all, I'm certain that combination has never been tested by the authors of either package:-)

Comment: Will update with full document. Apologies for that.

I thought they'd work based on this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/bordermatrix-with-blocks

Comment: @sbeleidy, as you found yourself, in the first example replace `\multicolumn{5}{c}{\text{Predicted}} ` with `\BAmulticolumn{5}{c}{\text{Predicted}} ` and it will works.

Comment: Well, that's embarassing. I completely missed that and saw it as multicolumn. Thank you @Zarko

Comment: @Zarko I'd completely forgotten about `\BAmulticolumn` (stupid command name, who wrote that package.....)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i know who is author :-). however after written 50+ packages (if i remember correctly) is difficult to remember all commands/macros names :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Zarko pointing out that the way to do multicolumns when using blockarray is to use `\BAmulticolumn` instead of `\multicolumn`. The final result is from the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
    & \BAmulticolumn{5}{c}{\text{Predicted}} & \\
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n & \\
    \begin{block}{c[ccccc]c}
        1 & c_{11}   & c_{12} & c_{13} & \dots & c_{1n} & \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{\text{Actual}}} \\
        2 & c_{21}   & c_{22} & c_{23} & \dots & c_{2n} & \\
        \vdots & \vdots   & \ddots &        &       & \vdots & \\
        n & c_{n1}   & c_{n2} & c_{n3} & \dots & c_{nn} & \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer (+1), however, please extend your code snippet  to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass...` and end with `\end{document}` that members can simple copy and test it.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of the eponymous package `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}
         & \Block{1-5}{\text{Predicted}} \\
         & 1      & 2      & 3      & \dots & n      & \\
  1      & c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & \dots & c_{1n} & \Block{4-1}{\rotate\text{Actual}} \\
  2      & c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & \dots & c_{2n} & \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &        &       & \vdots & \\
  n      & c_{n1} & c_{n2} & c_{n3} & \dots & c_{nn} & \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{3-2}{6-6}]
\end{NiceMatrix}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]