# How to write a column outside the braces in a matrix?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I would like to produce the following matrix : [image]:

My code is below which only produces the matrix without the additional column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{H}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 5\\
        1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
        4 & 1 & 2 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}
   \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/bordermatrix-with-blocks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility might be to employ `blkarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
\[\begin{blockarray}{(>{\:}cccc<{\:})l}
       1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 10\\
        1 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 10\\
        4 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{blockarray}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One possible option is just adding another `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{H}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 5\\
        1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
        4 & 1 & 2 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{matrix}
        10\\10\\10
    \end{matrix}
   \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Your solution works in this special case where all matrix cells have the standard height. It doesn't work when the cells contain something like `\frac{\frac12}3`.

Comment: Sure, LaTeX has many packages for dealing with cases with different complexities, but one should go for the simplest solution first, generalization has its cost!

Answer (score 5):

Considering that matrices are also arrays, I provide a version with basic LaTeX tools:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\mathbf{H}=\Bigg(
\begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 5\\
    1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
    4 & 1 & 2 & 4
\end{array}\Bigg)
\begin{array}{c}
    10\\
    10\\
    10
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT after the advice of the 2019-10-24 of the author of `nicematrix` *@F. Pantigny* reported in the comment.**

As another alternative you could add with appropriate modifications using the `nicematrix` package. For example using the environment `{pNiceMatrix}` with the option `last-col=5`.

You can see that you will have the same result as output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[\mathbf{H}= \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col=5]
1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 10\\
 1 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 10\\
4 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 10\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can delete row with `\phantom` and than replace `pNiceArrayRC` with `pNiceArrayC` and you will obtain the same result :-)

Comment: @Zarko Of course. :-)

Comment: @Zarko Don you know the reason of my downvote?

Comment: No, I don't know. Your answer not deserve this. Unfortunately I cant up-vote again :-(.

Comment: @Zarko I am not very expert of LaTeX but I have understood, many times, because I receveid severals downvotes without an explanation. I am very interesting to increase my experience in LaTeX and I'm not interesting for votes. Thank you very much always. Bye.

Comment: @Sebastino: You should update your answer because `{pNiceArrayC}` is now deprecated in the package `nicematrix`. You may use `{pNiceArray}` with the option `last-col` instead or even `{pNiceMatrix}` with the option `last-col=5`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny You're a friend :-) thanks. I think it's okay now.