# Block matrix with lines inside border matrix

Tags: matrices, nicematrix, bordermatrix

I'm wondering if anyone can help me typeset this border matrix with lines inside it. Dashed or solid lines are okay but I would prefer the lines to not extend past the brackets. I would also prefer to not need to load 3+ packages to get this to happen.

I have tried several other solutions I've found on StackExchange but they don't seem to work (I don't have kbordermatrix and nicematrix doesn't draw lines for some reason).

Any advice is appreciated.

[image: illustration]

EDIT: Here's my current code:

```
\bbordermatrix{
              & {\bf 1}        & {\bf 5}        & {\bf 2}     & {\bf 4}        & {\bf 3} \cr
    {\bf 1}\, & \nicefrac16    & \nicefrac56    & 0           & 0              & 0 \cr
    {\bf 5}\, & \nicefrac16    & \nicefrac56    & 0           & 0              & 0 \cr
    {\bf 2}   & 0              & 0              & \nicefrac23 & \nicefrac13    & 0 \cr
    {\bf 4}   & 0              & 0              & \nicefrac23 & \nicefrac13    & 0 \cr
    {\bf 3}   & \nicefrac1{36} & \nicefrac5{36} & \nicefrac59 & \nicefrac5{18} & 0
    }
```

I've started to troubleshoot what's going wrong with NiceMatrix. I have a header file that I include as \include{...}. Something in that header file seems to make this matrix (source: [bordermatrix with blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/bordermatrix-with-blocks)):

[image: nicegood]

come out like this:

[image: nicebad]

The problem is, I went through and commented out every line of code in that header and nothing seems to specifically be the problem.  In fact, if I don't include the header but just copy in every line, when I typeset the document the matrix first comes out wrong, but the second time I typeset it comes out right.  I've never seen this sort of behavior before... how can I get different results?

Then if I remove the lines of the header file and replace them with \include, I get the reverse behavior: the first time it will typeset correctly, and all subsequent times it will typeset incorrectly.

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If possible, could you edit into your question the code you have been working on with `nicematrix` that doesn't work please? It just helps people if there is a basis point. The author of `nicematrix` is often on this site so I am sure he would like to know why it isn't working, perhaps there is a bug in the code or something is missing from your attempt etc., it would be really helpful and would help people help you easier.

Comment: Answer updated with the bold face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `nicematrix`  and two custom rules.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xfrac} % nice fractions

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\NiceMatrixOptions
{
    custom-line ={command= H, tikz= dashed, width= 1mm}, % horizontal, dashed
    custom-line = {letter= I, tikz= dashed, width= 1mm}, % vertical, dashed
}
        
$\begin{bNiceArray}{cc I cc I c}[first-row, first-col, cell-space-top-limit=3pt, extra-margin=4pt]
        &1              &5              &2              &4              &3\\
    1   &\sfrac{1}{6}   &\sfrac{5}{6}   &0              &0              &0\\
    5   &\sfrac{1}{6}   &\sfrac{5}{6}   &0              &0              &0\\ \H % custom rule <<<<
    2   &0              &0              &\sfrac{2}{3}   &\sfrac{1}{3}   &0\\
    4   &0              &0              &\sfrac{2}{3}   &\sfrac{1}{3}   &0\\ \H % custom rule <<<<
    3   &\sfrac{1}{36}  &\sfrac{5}{36}  &\sfrac{5}{9}   &\sfrac{5}{18}  &0\\    
\end{bNiceArray}$
    
\end{document}
```

Used `nicematrix.sty    2022/05/08 v6.8a`

**Update** After follow-up question: bold face for the first column and the first row of the array. Use the keys

`code-for-first-row`  and `code-for-first-col`

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xfrac} % nice fractions

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\NiceMatrixOptions
{
    custom-line ={command= H, tikz= dashed, width= 1mm}, % horizontal, dashed
    custom-line = {letter= I, tikz= dashed, width= 1mm}, % vertical dashed  
}
        
$\begin{bNiceArray}{cc I cc I c}[first-row, first-col, cell-space-top-limit=3pt, extra-margin=4pt,  code-for-first-row = $\boldmath$, code-for-first-col = $\boldmath$]% changed <<<<<<<
        &1              &5              &2              &4              &3\\
    1   &\sfrac{1}{6}   &\sfrac{5}{6}   &0              &0              &0\\
    5   &\sfrac{1}{6}   &\sfrac{5}{6}   &0              &0              &0\\ \H % custom rule <<<<
    2   &0              &0              &\sfrac{2}{3}   &\sfrac{1}{3}   &0\\
    4   &0              &0              &\sfrac{2}{3}   &\sfrac{1}{3}   &0\\ \H % custom rule <<<<
    3   &\sfrac{1}{36}  &\sfrac{5}{36}  &\sfrac{5}{9}   &\sfrac{5}{18}  &0\\    
\end{bNiceArray}$
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks amazing but I get this error: Package nicematrix Error: The key 'custom-line' is unkno
wn for the command
(nicematrix)                \NiceMatrixOptions.
(nicematrix)                If you go on, it will be ignored.
(nicematrix)                For a list of the *principal* available keys,
(nicematrix)                type H <return>.

Comment: @Jeremy Weissmann You need version 6.6 or newer. I am using `nicematrix.sty    2022/05/08 v6.8a`  Put the command `\listfiles` before  `\documentclass` and look at the end of the .log file.

Comment: Okay I have updated my version of nicematrix. (Would be nice if TeXShop did this automatically.) But now I have the same problem that the dashed lines do not appear. They do if I replace my \include header with the lines from the header file.

Comment: @Jeremy Weissmann May be if you keep the options local ... See the update. Or use `\input` instead of `\include`.

Comment: Doesn't draw any of the lines, not even if I replace the custom rule with |

Comment: Holy moly. \input worked. Care to clue me in on the difference?

Comment: This is sort of a second question, but is there any easy way to get first-row and first-col in bold without manually doing it for each cell?

Comment: I will look. In any case thank you so much for unravelling this insane mystery with me!!

Comment: You have been incredibly helpful. I can’t thank you enough.

Comment: @Jeremy Weissmann Because you provided very good feedback!